# Como forçar a abertura de um link em outra aba e não janela?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um botão (âncora) que precisa ficar 'oculto', ou sem texto nenhum. A estrutura dele é esta:

```
<a class="testeimprimir" href="javascript:teste1();" target="_blank">TESTE</a>
```

A function é esta:

```
function teste1() {
    window.open('www.google.com.br', '_blank');
}
```

Se eu coloco `$('.testeimprimir').click()`, o evento do href não dispara e eu não posso colocar como onclick porque ao fazer o mesmo comando `$('.testeimprimir').click()` ele vai abrir uma nova janela e eu preciso que abra em uma nova ABA. Existe algum comando pra executar o href com JavaScript ou jQuery?

Comment: Comando para abrir uma nova aba? Desconheço essa funcionalidade em qualquer linguagem de programação.

Comment: Só o <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">abrir</a> faz abrir em uma nova ABA se você clicar, mesma coisa o window.open('www.google.com', '_blank'), porém o ultimo abre em uma nova JANELA se o método for chamando a partir de um onClick no <a onclick='metodo()'></a>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Como referido [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39624/223), o utilizador é quem decide se as novas janelas vão para uma aba ou para uma janela mesmo.

O conceito atualmente empregue pelos navegadores é que pedidos de novas janelas sejam abertos como nova aba salvo se o utilizador definir o contrário nas opções do seu navegador (de notar que isto não é um standard).

Parece-me que estás a tentar resolver algo não resolvível programaticamente uma vez que a decisão é do utilizador e está presente nas definições do navegador às quais não temos acesso programaticamente.

## Forçar abrir em nova aba

Até ao momento ainda não existe suporte oficial, mas em CSS existe uma proposta para lidar com este assunto:

```css
.novaAba {
    target-new: tab ! important
}
```

Alguns testes revelam que navegadores recentes dão suporte a esta propriedade.

Saber mais em [CSS3 Hyperlink Presentation Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/#target-new).

## Forçar abrir em nova janela

Salvo se o utilizador tiver definido no seu navegador para abrir sempre numa nova aba, o seguinte código permite abrir numa nova janela porque efetivamente estamos a indicar detalhes como a altura, detalhes esses que indicam ao navegador que pretendemos uma nova janela e não uma aba:

```js
window.open("http://www.google.com/", "minhaJanela", "height=200,width=200");
```

Estas e outras opções da nova janela podem ser consultadas [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open).

Answer (score 13):

Seu HTML e o JavaScript são redundantes. O `target="_blank"` no HTML já força a abertura do link em uma nova janela, então o JS, que faz a mesma coisa, é desnecessário. Você poderia usar simplesmente HTML, assim:

```
<a class="testeimprimir" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">TESTE</a>
```

Agora, se a página irá abrir em outra janela ou outra aba, é uma decisão do browser. O Chrome, por exemplo, costuma forçar uma nova aba. Isso é configurável em cada browser, e não existe maneira de controlar, em JS ou HTML, se a abertura será em outra aba ou outra janela.

Comment: Isso é verdade! Mas o meu caso é o seguinte: Eu quero que o evento click do <a> seja chamado por JQuery ou Javascript assim: $('.testeimprimir').click(), pois ele só vai acontecer no success de um AJAX. Se eu colocar o método teste1() no success ele vai funcionar, porém vai abrir em uma NOVA JANELA do navegador e eu preciso que ele abra em uma nova ABA e está linha window.open('www.google.com.br', '_blank'); o _blank não funciona, pelo menos pra mim.

Comment: [Algo assim?](http://jsfiddle.net/bcu0d8af/)

Comment: Quase isso, preciso que no href venha um javascript:ChamarMetodo(), ou colocar o método todo nessa linha, tanto faz.

Comment: Eu evitaria javascript no href. É má prática... Tente definir o que acontece no clique em outro lugar (com jQuery, usando um `$('#id-do-link').click(function(){ /* AQUI */ })`)

Answer (score 5):

Cara seu código ta praticamente certo, só faltou um http:// na frente do link do google, veja como coloquei aqui e funcionou:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
      function teste1() {
        window.open('http://www.google.com.br', '_blank');
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a class="testeimprimir" href="javascript:teste1();" 
    target="_blank">TESTE</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Se mandar executar aqui não vai funcionar pq o Stack Overflow bloqueia o redirecionamento de páginas então coloquei ele no Plunker da uma olhada [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DRvlC9Dl35FeaEDKjPuW?p=preview)

Comment: Pra mim também funciona, mas só se eu ir e clicar com o mouse, o que eu preciso é chamar o click com Javascript ou Jquery, mas não está funcionando.

Answer (score 2):

você pode também fazer bom uso deste, tal como eu fiz:

```
window.open("url", "_blank");
```

Fonte: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar uma const com a url e fazer uma function pra abrir a url em uma nova janela da seguinte forma em React:

```
const google = 'https://google.com';

function openNewTab(url) {
    const win = window.open(url, '_blank')
    win.focus()
}
```

Ai é só associar a url "google" como parâmetro da sua função chamada no button. Abaixo exemplo:

```
<button onClick={() => openNewTab(google)}> Google </button>
```