# abrir link em nova aba com JS ou Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

montei um site utilizando o Mobirize e ele tem um ícone do Facebook que quando clicado você compartilha o site no seu face como um post. Gostaria que ao invés disso ele abrisse uma nova aba com uma pagina especifica do Facebook.No caso o que abre o popup é o codigo
 `popupUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={url}',`

codigo:

```
var services = {
    facebook: {
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/
        counterUrl: 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+total_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22{url}%22&callback=?',
        convertNumber: function(data) {
            return data.data[0].total_count;
        },
        popupUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={url}',
        popupWidth: 600,
        popupHeight: 359
    },
```

Comment: Um `target="_blank"` não resolve ?

Comment: [Como forçar a abertura de um link em outra aba e não janela?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39620/4808)

Comment: só que ele abre um popup eu queria que abrisse outra aba com a Pagina do facebook, e não comum campo pra comprtilhar o site na timeline

Answer (score 0):

Ja descobri, tive que atualizar esse codigo acima para esse:

```
var services = {
    facebook: {
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/
        counterUrl: 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+total_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22{url}%22&callback=?',
        convertNumber: function(data) {
            return data.data[0].total_count;
        },
        window.open: 'https://www.facebook.com/dungeongamebar',
        popupWidth: 600,
        popupHeight: 359
    },
```